# save multiple records at once(bulk commit), in Ember 2.2

Tags: ember.js

I know this subject has already been posted around stackoverflow and other forums, still I can't find exact answer.

Single record creation and commit works fine with createRecord and save functions. How do it for bulk record creation and commit it to server? I'm using JSONAPI adapter.

I've read in a discussion that one way would be to create a custom adapter, but I'm not sure what is the correct place to do that... maybe to create saveAllRecords() function or another way is to use pushpayload.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

I'm a bit late to the party but you could do the following.

Create a new model that has a property modelList which will contain all the models you want to save.

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
    modelList: DS.hasMany('model')
});
```

You will need to create a custom serializer and use the EmbeddedRecordsMixin.

```
import DS from 'ember-data';
import Ember from 'ember';

export default DS.JSONAPISerializer.extend(DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin,{
    attrs: {
        participants: {
            embedded: 'always'
        }
    }
});
```

In your route/controller create the new model and fill the list.

```
let modelList = this.store.createRecord('model-list', {modelList: [obj1, obj2, obj3]});
```

The you can save the modelList object with:

```
modelList.save()
```

This will include all the models in the payload and send them to your to your backend where you can access the list and safe them individually.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest using a promise array as follows (since `.save()` returns a promise):

```
let jobs = items.map(item => item.save());

Promise.all(jobs).then(items => {
    // Do whatever
});
```

Comment: Be forewarned though that's a new server call for each `.save` in that `.map` function.

Comment: Not what I was looking for, but nonetheless very helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do like :

```
let obj1 = this.get('store').createRecord('model', {/*values*/});
let obj2 = this.get('store').createRecord('model', {/*values*/});
let obj3 = this.get('store').createRecord('model', {/*values*/});

...

unsavedRecord: Ember.computed(function({
  return this.get('store').peekAll('model').filterBy('isNew', true);
}))

...

actions: {
  save(){
  this.get('unsavedRecord').forEach(function(model){
  model.save();
});
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I want to push all 3 records at single time, not to call server thrice.

Comment: @Jerry Ah, so you need to create your own method in adapter

Answer (score 0):

You could create a custom adapter but it would be a dirty solution and I´m not sure how you would use multiple objects in there with the given methods.

If your model isn´t too complex I would prefer you´ll send custom payload to your server.

I´m using this to send simple positional updates for a list which is sortable by the user. My original model is huge with 30+ attributes and relations. That way I can send all positional updates at once.

Just as example it looks something like this.

```
var simplified_modules = [];

forEach(...){
    var simple = {
              id: entity.get('id'),
              position: entity.get('newPosition')
             };

    simplified_modules.addObject(simple);
}

Ember.$.ajax(Hosturl + "/lists/update_positions, {
        type: 'POST',
        data: JSON.stringify({
            updated_module_positions: simplified_modules
        }),
        contentType: 'application/json',
        .......
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I see is to reopen [Ember.Array](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Array.html) class and define a property 'saveAll', which would have approximately such content:

```
Ember.Array.reopen({
    saveAll: function () {
        if (this.length) {
            var serializedObject = {}; //
            this.forEach(function (element) {
                if (element.save) {
                    //TODO: 1) serialize element and push it to
                    //the serializedObject
                    //2) then you can manually make ajax call or
                    //make a method inside you adapter, and call it
                    //from here like this: "adapter.customSave(data);"
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```